# Explain:function returns same function in go

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    go spinner(100 * time.Millisecond)
    const n = 45
    fibN := fib(n) // slow
    fmt.Printf("\rFibonacci(%d) = %d\n", n, fibN)
}

func spinner(delay time.Duration) {
    for {
        for _, r := range `-\|/` {
            fmt.Printf("\r%c", r)
            time.Sleep(delay)
        }
    }
}

func fib(x int) int {
    if x < 2 {
        return x
    }
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
}
```

can you explain above fib function ,how the results are obtained.

fib function return a fib calls ,how does the end results come?

Comment: Hint : Research recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in this function:

```
func fib(x int) int {
    if x < 2 {
        return x
    }
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
}
```

If `x<2` the function returns immediately, if not it retrieves the result from a call to `fib` with a smaller value of `x`

For recursive calls there are the 3 Laws of Recursion:

1. A recursive algorithm must have a base case.
2. A recursive algorithm
   must change its state and move toward the base case.
3. A recursive
   algorithm must call itself, recursively.

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/TheThreeLawsofRecursion.html

In your example, the base case is when `x < 2`. The state change is the reduction by 1 or 2 and your function calls itself recursively so the three laws are met.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification,i understood the laws of recursion.

Comment: But what i didn't get was the main function has statement  fibN := fib(45) ,and finally returns result  .    how the fib function returning the result,at any cost only numeric return was when it is x <2

Comment: Because the call to fib(45) will block while the calls to fib(44) and fib(43) are executed, fib(44) will block on fib(43) and fib(42). The call to  fib(43) will block until fib(42) and fib(41)  return  so on. 
These build up a stack of calls until fib(1) or fib(0) which will return and the stack unwinds and each call returns a value to its caller.

Comment: You are true,but where i didn't get was what is the result of fib(44),fib(43)...so on..because there is no single step to calculate that...finally how it accumulate to answer 1134903170.............

Comment: Try it on pen and paper to calculate fib(5)

Write out your stack frames.

I can't help more than that. This is very very basic recursion